# Hierarchical Linear Modeling With Binary Outcomes

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

I am an ungrad helping out with a Prof and have had no luck trying to figure out what to do with the data. I have age, gender, experimental condition (Condition 1, 2, 3-between subjects), agexcondition, genderxcondition as my predictors, and the dependent variable is binary (outcome A or B).

The thing is, the participants were recruited from schools, so that means that the data is nested and requires some kind of analysis that takes into account the nested structure. But one complication is that I do not have the schools of 50 out of 300 of the participants. Apparently, the RAs "didn't think it was important to encode". I read some paper that suggested listwise deletion of missing Lvl 2 data, but that will result in losing so much valuable data.

Another complication is that after I consulted Prof, he told me to not think "so complicated" and just ignore the nested structure. I could carry on with multinominal logistic regression but I have the nagging feeling that the right way to go is still the generalized linear mixed model.

So please can someone enlighten me on what I can do?

1. GLMM or multinominal logistic regression?
2. If GLMM, What to do with the large chunks of missing level 2 data?
3. How to conduct GLMM using R? (Do I use the glmer function of lme4?)

Comment: Two general themes: (i) try simple stuff first (ii) if time, try everything!

First thing I'd try: (1) logistic regression on full sample ignoring school (2) logistic regression on subsample where you have school and take school into account: (a) just as another variable and (b) maybe with full interactive terms (you may not have much power here). Often times experimental results are laid out with increasing levels of controls (reg#1, reg#2, reg#3 etc...). If school doesn't affect the estimates much, then it may not be much of an issue.  Just some quick thoughts.